# Mysql syntax help

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064, table-lock

Query:

```
select t1.col1
  from table1 t1
inner join with (nolock) table2 t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Am trying to use nolock option for optimized query in mySQL db, but for some reason the above query 
does not work and the error i receive is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

MySQL doesn't support `with (nolock)`, that's an SQL Server thing.

Here's an article talking about getting an equivalent effect in MySQL: [MySQL with nolock](http://www.sqldba.org/articles/22-mysql-with-nolock.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`WITH(NOLOCK)` seems to be in MSSQL ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28SQL.105%29.aspx))

In MySQL InnoDB you have this equivalent `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

[See on MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,81970,82201#msg-82201)